# Redirection for admin and user after login

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm new to PHP and in the process of creating a simple login and booking system. I'm stuck on validating the login page. It's supposed to redirect the user to either the user menu or admin menu, but for some reason, it always comes back with "Incorrect password, please try again. Click Here to Log In" even if the password is right. What is the problem?

---

checkLogin1.php

```
<?php
// Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("maxizoo") or die(mysql_error());
//Checks if there is a login cookie
if (isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site'])) {
//if there is, it logs you in and directes you to the members page
    $uid = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site'];
    $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registrants WHERE userid = '$uid'") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($check)) {
        if ($pass != $info['password']) {

        } else {
            if ($info['admin'] == '1') { // check the value of the 'admin' in the db
                //go to admin area
                header("Location: adminMenu.php");
            } else {
                //go to members area
                header("Location: studentMenu.php");
            }
        }
    }
}
//if the login form is submitted 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // if form has been submitted
    // makes sure they filled it in
    if (!$_POST['uid'] | !$_POST['pass']) {
        die('You did not fill in a required field.');
    }
    // checks it against the database
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

    }
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registrants WHERE userid = '" . $_POST['uid'] . "'") or die(mysql_error());
    //Gives error if user dosen't exist
    $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);
    if ($check2 == 0) {
        die('That user does not exist in our database. <a href=registration.php>Click Here to Register</a>');
    }
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($check)) {
        $_POST['pass'] = stripslashes($_POST['pass']);
        $info['password'] = stripslashes($info['password']);
        $_POST['pass'] = md5($_POST['pass']);
        //gives error if the password is wrong
        if ($_POST['pass'] != $info['password']) {
            die('Incorrect password, please try again. <a href=login.php>Click Here to Log In</a>');
        } else {
            // if login is ok then we add a cookie 
            $_POST['uid'] = stripslashes($_POST['uid']);
            $hour = time() + 3600;
            setcookie(ID_my_site, $_POST['uid'], $hour);
            setcookie(Key_my_site, $_POST['pass'], $hour);
            //then redirect them to the members area 
            header("Location: studenMenu.php");
        }
    }
} else {
    // if they are not logged in 
    ?> 
    <form action="checkLogin1.php" method="post"> 
        <table border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' bordercolor='#FF9900' bgcolor="#CCFFFF"> 
            <tr><td colspan=2><h1>Login</h1></td></tr> 
            <tr><td>User ID:</td><td> 
                    <input type="text" name="uid" maxlength="40"> 
                </td></tr> 
            <tr><td>Password:</td><td> 
                    <input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="50"> 
                </td></tr> 
            <tr><td colspan="2" align="right"> 
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"> 
                </td></tr> 
        </table> 
        <br />
        <a href="/hrd/orig/registration.php">Register Here</a>
    </form> 
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: So, I'm assuming that we're looking at checkLogin1.php?

Comment: Yes this is checkLogin1.php

Comment: Firstly you should stop using mysql_* functions and start using mysqli_* or PDO functions instead.

Second your code has SQL injection problems where you are taking user input ($_POST) and just putting this straight into an SQL query without any form of escaping, if you are not switching to mysqli, pdo or another type of database access, at least use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Thirdly, as a newish php user I would suggest that you use a pre-rolled authentication system rather than build your own as there are too many pitfalls that you will not be aware of.

Comment: My initial thought (that I can't validate now, since I'm a tad busy), is that passwords currently in the database are not MD5-hashed, which would cause a failure each time. Also (not related to your particular issue), there's a typo in your login-ok header; it appears to be looking for 'studenMenu.php' instead of 'studentMenu.php'

Comment: This system is for a college project, thats why it might not be the best security. As I'm new to php i would like to use the most simple way of building it. * fixed the typo

Comment: Yes the passwords are not hashed in the database, what part would i need to take out for the md5?

Comment: Take out $_POST['pass'] = md5($_POST['pass']);

Comment: Thank yous all for the help that did the trick ;) possible i will have a few more post today asking about my other problems soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's this:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registrants WHERE userid = '$uid'")or die(mysql_error());
```

it's just doing a lookup for a userId of '$uid' rather than the value. Try this:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registrants WHERE userid = '".$uid."'")or die(mysql_error());
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: While this is advisable to make the code clearer, it's not necessarily _the_ problem; when a string in PHP uses double-quotes, variables will be parsed within it (see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) for more details)

Comment: Thanks Chris, I did wonder if there was an automatic parsing doohickey :)

Answer (score 0):

If the users in the database table have unhashed passwords, then comparing those passwords to the MD5 version will fail every time. In your registration logic, the following should be what you need (roughly):

```
...
$p = md5($_POST['newpassword']);
$q = "INSERT INTO registrants (userid, password) VALUES ('" 
        . $_POST['userid'] . "', '" . $p . "')";
// Execute query as normal
...
```